# Automapper mapping properties

Tags: c#, automapper, dto

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
public class EntityDto
{
    int EntityId { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    EntityId<int> EntityId { get; }
}

public class EntityId<T>
{
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

What is the appropriate way for defining the mapping profile in this case?
Both directions, of course.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering about direction - you want to map `EntityId<T>` to `Entity` to `EntityDto` and backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that your classes look like this:

```
class EntityDto
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}

class EntityId<T>
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
    public EntityId<int> EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

mapping will look like this:

```
    static void CreateMapForEntityId<T>()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<T, EntityId<T>>()
            .ForMember(_ => _.Id, options => options.MapFrom(_ => _));
    }

    static void TestMapping(int id)
    {
        CreateMapForEntityId<int>();

        Mapper
            .CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>()
            .ForMember(_ => _.EntityId, options => options.MapFrom(_ => _.EntityId.Id))
            .ReverseMap();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var entity = new Entity { EntityId = new EntityId<int> { Id = id } };

        var entityDto = Mapper.Map<EntityDto>(entity);
        Debug.Assert(entityDto.EntityId == id);

        var entityClone = Mapper.Map<Entity>(entityDto);
        Debug.Assert(entityClone.EntityId.Id == id);
    }
```

Basically, there won't be any "auto"-mapping.

Comment: This worked!
Now the following exception is thrown:
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Method 'GetEnumerator' in type IEnumerable<TItem> is not implemented.

The structure is as follows:
class UnauthorizedItemsDto
    {
        InspectableItemDto[] PeerToPeerApplications { get; set; }
    }
public interface IUnauthorizedItems
    {
        IEnumerable<IInspectableItem> PeerToPeerApplications { get; }        
    }

Comment: This exception is unrelated to the question. At least, it can't be thrown using code in the answer.